# Transparent .png including glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm using cycles to get a realistic glass material. I have `Transparent` and `Transparent Glass` checked in `Film`. I have a simple principled BSDF with full transmission. The resulting .png has a transparent background, but the transparent parts of the glass are just gray:

[image]

Is there any way to make the gray parts of the glassy object transparent?

**Edit:** Cranking up the transparent glass roughness threshold to 1 helps a bit, but does not completely eliminate the gray bits:

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me, maybe share your file?

Comment: @moonboots https://www.dropbox.com/s/hoh9hpdo5syo44w/transparency.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as it is supposed to, to make it more transparent you can lower down the *Roughness*, to avoid any grey reflection you can make the world white (or any other color) instead of grey (or you can turn off its *Ray Visibility*), and also choose a 100% white as *Base Colo*r:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With only the default Principled BSDF's transmission set to 1, I need to crank up the Transparent Glass' Roughness Threshold a bit:

[image: threshold]

I start seeing significant results at 0.5.

Comment: It did help a bit, but there are still gray regions (see my edits).

Comment: That's because you are in a gray environment. Reflections don't reflect only the white lamp, they reflect everything.